# update property in a yaml file

Tags: go, yaml

Im reading a yaml file modify a **specific field** `test1` to `test2` and I want to write it back to file
The problem that the raw data is display as numbers and I got a lot empty fields (which is related to the struct but I want to avoid it,
How I make it works? I mean just update the property of the yaml file and write it back to a new file.

**This is what I’ve tried**

https://go.dev/play/p/Fop37gRwmjR?v=goprev

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/gardener/gardener/pkg/apis/core/v1beta1"
    gyaml "github.com/go-yaml/yaml/v3"
    "io/ioutil"
    "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/runtime"
    "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/yaml"
)

type InfraConfig struct {
    APIVersion string `json:"apiVersion,omitempty"`
    Kind       string `json:"kind,omitempty"`
    Networks   struct {
        CloudNAT struct {
            MinPortsPerVM int `json:"minPortsPerVM,omitempty"`
            NatIPNames    []struct {
                Name string `json:"name,omitempty"`
            } `json:"natIPNames,omitempty"`
        } `json:"cloudNAT,omitempty"`
    } `json:"networks,omitempty"`
}

func main() {
    shoot, e := parseShoot("test.yaml")
    if e != nil {
        fmt.Println(e)
    }

    var existingInfraConfig InfraConfig
    err := json.Unmarshal(shoot.Spec.Provider.InfrastructureConfig.Raw, &existingInfraConfig)
    fmt.Println(err)

    existingInfraConfig.Networks.CloudNAT.NatIPNames[0].Name = "test2"
    byteData, _ := json.Marshal(existingInfraConfig)

    shoot.Spec.Provider.InfrastructureConfig = &runtime.RawExtension{
        Raw:    byteData,
        Object: nil,
    }
    fmt.Println(string(shoot.Spec.Provider.InfrastructureConfig.Raw))

    aa, e := gyaml.Marshal(shoot)
    if e != nil {
        fmt.Println(e)

    }
    ioutil.WriteFile("test2.yaml", aa, 0644)
    }
func parseShoot(path string) (*v1beta1.Shoot, error) {
    var shootSpec *v1beta1.Shoot
    bytes, err := ioutil.ReadFile(path)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    err = yaml.Unmarshal(bytes, &shootSpec)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return shootSpec, nil
}

// this is the yaml


apiVersion: core.gardener.cloud/v1beta1
kind: Shoot
metadata:
  name: test
  namespace: ns
spec:
  provider:
    type: aaa
    infrastructureConfig:
      apiVersion: gcp.provider.extensions.gardener.cloud/v1alpha1
      kind: InfrastructureConfig
      networks:
        cloudNAT:
          minPortsPerVM: 10000
          natIPNames:
            - name: test1
```

This is what I got after writing the data to a file.

```
typemeta:
  kind: Shoot
  apiversion: core.gardener.cloud/v1beta1
objectmeta:
  name: test
  generatename: ""
  namespace: ns
  selflink: ""
  uid: ""
  resourceversion: ""
  generation: 0
  creationtimestamp: "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
  deletiontimestamp: null
  deletiongraceperiodseconds: null
  labels: {}
  annotations: {}
  ownerreferences: []
  finalizers: []
  clustername: ""
  managedfields: []
spec:
  addons: null
  cloudprofilename: ""
  dns: null
  extensions: []
  hibernation: null
  kubernetes:
    allowprivilegedcontainers: null
    clusterautoscaler: null
    kubeapiserver: null
    kubecontrollermanager: null
    kubescheduler: null
    kubeproxy: null
    kubelet: null
    version: ""
    verticalpodautoscaler: null
  networking:
    type: ""
    providerconfig: null
    pods: null
    nodes: null
    services: null
  maintenance: null
  monitoring: null
  provider:
    type: aaa
    controlplaneconfig: null
    infrastructureconfig:
      raw:
      - 123
      - 34
      - 97
      - 112
      - 105
      - 86
      - 101
      - 114
      - 115
      - 105
      - 111
      - 110
      - 34
      - 58
      - 34
      - 103
      - 99
      - 112
      - 46
      - 112
      - 114
      - 111
      - 118
      - 105
      - 100
      - 101
      - 114
      - 46
      - 101
      - 120
      - 116
      - 101
      - 110
      - 115
      - 105
      - 111
      - 110
      - 115
      - 46
      - 103
      - 97
      - 114
      - 100
      - 101
      - 110
      - 101
      - 114
      - 46
      - 99
      - 108
      - 111
      - 117
      - 100
      - 47
      - 118
      - 49
      - 97
      - 108
      - 112
      - 104
      - 97
      - 49
      - 34
      - 44
      - 34
      - 107
      - 105
      - 110
      - 100
      - 34
      - 58
      - 34
      - 73
      - 110
      - 102
      - 114
      - 97
      - 115
      - 116
      - 114
      - 117
      - 99
      - 116
      - 117
      - 114
      - 101
      - 67
      - 111
      - 110
      - 102
      - 105
      - 103
      - 34
      - 44
      - 34
      - 110
      - 101
      - 116
      - 119
      - 111
      - 114
      - 107
      - 115
      - 34
      - 58
      - 123
      - 34
      - 99
      - 108
      - 111
      - 117
      - 100
      - 78
      - 65
      - 84
      - 34
      - 58
      - 123
      - 34
      - 109
      - 105
      - 110
      - 80
      - 111
      - 114
      - 116
      - 115
      - 80
      - 101
      - 114
      - 86
      - 77
      - 34
      - 58
      - 49
      - 48
      - 48
      - 48
      - 48
      - 44
      - 34
      - 110
      - 97
      - 116
      - 73
      - 80
      - 78
      - 97
      - 109
      - 101
      - 115
      - 34
      - 58
      - 91
      - 123
      - 34
      - 110
      - 97
      - 109
      - 101
      - 34
      - 58
      - 34
      - 116
      - 101
      - 115
      - 116
      - 51
      - 34
      - 125
      - 93
      - 125
      - 125
      - 125
      object: null
    workers: []
  purpose: null
  region: ""
  secretbindingname: ""
  seedname: null
  seedselector: null
  resources: []
  tolerations: []
  exposureclassname: null
  systemcomponents: null
status:
  conditions: []
  constraints: []
  gardener:
    id: ""
    name: ""
    version: ""
  ishibernated: false
  lastoperation: null
  lasterrors: []
  observedgeneration: 0
  retrycyclestarttime: null
  seedname: null
  technicalid: ""
  uid: ""
  clusteridentity: null
  advertisedaddresses: []
  migrationstarttime: null
  credentials: null
```

**UPDATE**

This is the complete file

```
apiVersion: core.gardener.cloud/v1beta1
kind: Shoot
metadata:
  name: test
  namespace: ns
spec:
  provider:
    type: aaa
    infrastructureConfig:
      apiVersion: gcp.provider.extensions.gardener.cloud/v1alpha1
      kind: InfrastructureConfig
      networks:
        cloudNAT:
          minPortsPerVM: 10000
          natIPNames:
            - name: test1
```

Comment: What's `parseShoot`? What's `shoot.Spec.Provider.InfrastructureConfig.Raw`? You don't import this. Also you seem to parse some „raw“ JSON inside the YAML which doesn't exist, that's very confusing. Have you considered just doing `yq e '.spec.provider.infrastructureConfig.networks.cloudNAT.natIPNames[0].name = "test2"' test.yaml > test2.yaml`?

Comment: @flyx- thanks but how should I do it with Go program?

Comment: @flyx - i've update the question with the parseShoot as requested

Comment: [yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq) *is* a Go program. The problem is that you use external types which you cannot annotate with `\`yaml:"<name>,omitemty"\``. In particular, `InfrastructureConfig` seems to be a *very* strange thing. You'd be better off just using `gyaml.Node` and `yq` basically does that so there's no obvious reason to reimplement it.

Comment: Can you please share how would you do it with the `gyaml.Node` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's minimal code to show how using `yaml.Node` generally works:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"

    "gopkg.in/yaml.v3"
)

var input = []byte(`
spec:
  provider:
    infrastructureConfig:
      networks:
        cloudNAT:
          natIPNames:
            - name: test
`)

func set(root *yaml.Node, path []string, value yaml.Node) {
    if len(path) == 0 {
        *root = value
        return
    }
    key := path[0]
    rest := path[1:]
    switch root.Kind {
    case yaml.DocumentNode:
        set(root.Content[0], path, value)
    case yaml.MappingNode:
        for i := 0; i < len(root.Content); i += 2 {
            if root.Content[i].Value == key {
                set(root.Content[i+1], rest, value)
                return
            }
        }
    case yaml.SequenceNode:
        index, err := strconv.Atoi(key)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        set(root.Content[index], rest, value)
    }
}

func main() {
    var doc yaml.Node
    if err := yaml.Unmarshal(input, &doc); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    newVal := yaml.Node{
        Kind:  yaml.ScalarNode,
        Value: "test2",
    }
    set(&doc, []string{"spec", "provider", "infrastructureConfig", "networks", "cloudNAT", "natIPNames", "0", "name"}, newVal)
    out, err := yaml.Marshal(doc.Content[0])
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(out))
}
```

[On Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/WjJSf3pYT49)

**This code is dangerous** since it ignores lots of invalid and error cases. A completely robust implementation is beyond an SO answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot! 1+ last question, how would you do it for existing file and update just this section, as this section is part of a file

Comment: @JJD Just override the file? Nodes do hold a `Line` and `Column` field which you can theoretically use to find the starting point in the file that needs to be changed, but the *end* of the Node is missing so the information doesn't suffice to replace the node's text (also that would horribly break if the node is multiline because changing the file directly while ignoring YAML syntax will get you incorrect indentations).